# Sitecore Filtering by Field Value on Query of GraphQL

Tags: jss, graphql

I am currently working on trying out the Sitecore GraphQL Query where I just get all the items of a specific location in the Sitecore Tree. However, I may need to filter the item results based on a particular Field Value. Is it possible to do this on the GraphQL in Connected mode?

Comment: hope this helps you. https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/8-filtering-pagination-and-sorting/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an index search and filter whatever, Use somethings like this:

```
{
  search(
    fieldsEqual:[{name:"title", value:"Sit*" }] rootItem:"/sitecore/content"
        ) {
    results {
      items {
        item {
          id
          name
          path
          url
          field(name  : "title") {
           title: value
          }
        }
      }
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

This is searching, filtering on Title field in the tree below rootItem.
For only searching in a specific location you can filter on parent id.
somethings like this:

`fieldsEqual:[{name:"title", value:"Sit*"} ,{name:"_parent",value:"0de95ae441ab4d019eb067441b7c2450"}]`

Comment: How can i execute the same query in Sitecore xGraph browser? @Jan Bluemink

Comment: This Query works also in Sitecore Experience Graph Browser go to /sitecore/api/graph/items/web/ui or the endpoint you have setup.

Comment: Cannot query field \"search\" on type \"Query\".  error showing up after executing the query. @Jan Bluemink

Comment: on /sitecore/api/graph/items/master/schema (url depend on your endpoint) you can see the schema.. and there should be a line: type Query {
  item(path: String, language: String, version: Int): Item
  sites(name: String = "", current: Boolean = false, includeSystemSites: Boolean = false): [SiteGraphType]
  templates(path: String): [ItemTemplate]
  search(first: Int, after: String = 0, rootItem: String, keyword: String, language: String, latestVersion: Boolean = true, index: String, fieldsEqual: [ItemSearchFieldQuery], facetOn: [String!]): ContentSearchResults
}

Comment: Thanks for the Info. This line is not present in my graph schema. anything did i missed here? @Jan Bluemink

Comment: What version are you using? are you running the default config?

Comment: I am using Sitecore JavaScript Services Server for Sitecore 9.0 11.0.0 rev. 181031. I am using default config. @Jan Bluemink

Comment: you can found the search think in the \App_Config\Sitecore\Services.GraphQL\Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.config   in the <systemContent>  .. <queries hint="raw:AddQuery">
...
<query name="search" type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.Queries.SearchQuery, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content" />